# ftp server log to include more information

Tags: logs, ftp, vsftpd

I am implementing the ftp server on linux box (fedora 11, `vsftpd`). Everything works good so far but i need Ftp server log files  to contain transfer rate information.

At the moment when I use "get " or " put" command from client end , I got following message on ftp client

example

```
ftp: 18 bytes received in 0.00seconds 18000.00kbytes/sec.
```

Is there is any way , I can get same message on ftp server side?

Below is the sample of my xferlog file

```
Tue Oct 23 01:28:52 2012 1 10.65.112.55 1 /home/test/testfile b _ o r test ftp 0 * c 
Tue Oct 23 01:32:46 2012 1 10.65.112.55 18 /home/test/uploadServer b _ i r test ftp 0 * c 
Tue Oct 23 01:50:23 2012 1 192.168.10.27 1 /home/test/testfile a _ o r test ftp 0 * c 
Tue Oct 23 01:50:36 2012 1 192.168.10.27 19 /home/test/test a _ i r test ftp 0 * c
```

Comment: You'll need to say which FTP Daemon you're using, because this feature may or may not be available depending on the product in question.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I have installed the ftp package vsftpd-2.2.2-6.fc12.i686.rpm

Comment: Do i need to change conf file to include those information

Comment: I don't know how long your config file is, but it may be worth adding it to the end of your query.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.   
 Well I have solved that.
 I have included 
***dual_log_enable= yes*** in the vsftpd.conf file and as a result it created the new log file  as /var/log/vsftpd.log  and it contains all the information that I need.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: with reputation less than 8 i cant able to mark it as solved lol

Comment: Okay, after a few hours (maybe a day?) you can create an answer for your own question with that detail, and then accept it as the accepted answer.